# C++ - Continuing a while loop upon exception

Tags: c++, loops, exception, return

When an exception is encountered in C++, does the program automatically terminate upon catching it. Is there a way that ,if the exception was caught within a loop, I could just skip the rest of the loop and go straight to the next iteration?

Comment: Can you post the code for the advance() function.

Comment: Put another 'if' loop that checks to see if 'in!= "South" ' - and put the two statements inside the condition so it will execute only if 'in' is not equal to South.

Comment: exceptions are handled with `try` `catch` blocks. I can't spot those in your code.

Comment: @Maertin `if` isn't a _loop_.

Comment: @Winter. I'm sorry but I can't put that code up. This is for a school assignment, and I'll probably get in trouble for posting more than the skeleton online.

Comment: But my question is, can it be done with exceptions? Wouldn't the code just terminate? That's not what I am trying to do

Comment: You don't want to post the whole project anyway. Reduce the problem to the minimum possible code that reproduces the error, and if doing that doesn't have you staring at the screen in dismay and then fixing the bug, post the reduced code. [This is what's called an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you cannot easily extract a MCVE, odds are very good that you have two problems: The bug and a bad design.

Comment: If you are detecting where the player is on the board then this can be done with one if statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways to solve this problem.

- Create a member function that checks whether a move is valid before making it. The calling code will need to call this function before calling `advance`, and only call `advance` if the move is valid.
- Make the `advance` member function return a value indicating whether the player's position was advanced. The calling code will need to test the return value to decide whether to print the board or print a "try again" type of message.
- Make the `advance` member function throw an exception if the move is invalid. The calling code will need to catch the exception.

There are lots of other ways to solve this problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, if that snipped of code is EXACTLY how you copy-pasted it, it has some syntax errors. This is how it should be written:

```
     int main() {
     ...
     Person *p = new Person("Neo");
     ...
     string in;
     while(cin >> in) {
      if (in == "q") {
       break;
      }
      else if (in == /*One of the eight directions North ... Northwest*/) {
       p->advance(in);
      } //this bracket here ends the if. after the parentheses, nothing else will execute
      else {
       cerr << "Input one of the eight directions" < endl;
      }
     }
    }
```

So yeah, if I understood correctly your problem, adding that closing bracket there should solve it. I hope this is what you needed and that it was helpful

Comment: The only syntax error was the missing semicolon after `p->printBoard()`. Eliminating the calls to `system("clear")` and `p->printBoard()` does not solve the problem.

Comment: that wasn't the only thing I changed. Although not technically incorrect, I changed the second "if" into an "else if" and the comment "one of the eight...." into a /* */ comment as it was changing the open brackett